# grouping events in C#

Tags: c#, events

Is there any ready to use solution to group events?

Say I have two events: A and B.
I want a Method M to be executed when A and B have been fired, they do not need to fire exactly at the same time.

Something like:
Group event G fires after both, A and B have fired. I need to register Method M only at Group event G.

A can fire more than one time, G will only fire after B has fired. Same other way.

I'm looking for a library, which has these events.

Edit: Example

```
Events:
    A | B | G
1   F   0   0
2   0   F   F
3   0   F   0 
4   0   F   0 
5   0   F   0 
6   F   0   F
7   F   0   0
8   0   F   F
9   0   0   0 
10  F   F   F
```

*F* means the event fires, 
*0* it does not.

Comment: Not aware about anything like that, but what if you have say a,a,a,b,b fired, how many times g should be fired in this case ?

Comment: Or are you guaranteeing in your code that A and B only fire once for a given instance? More details would really help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx).

Look at the [Observable.FromEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.fromevent%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) (or Observable.FromEventPattern) method to convert standard .NET event to observable and then you can group the results using [Observable.CombineLatest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211991%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

Here is a pseudo code:

```
var observableA = Observable.FromEvent(yourEventA);
var observableB = Observable.FromEvent(yourEventB);

var observableG = observableA.CombineLatest(observableB, ...)
```

The generated observable is triggered when both events are triggered.

EDIT

`CombineLatest` produce an output with the latest results, without resetting its state. So for example if A1 is fired then B1 is fired G1 is produced with (A1 + B1), but if B2 is fired then G2 is produced with (A1 + B2) and so on...

To exactly produce your expected results you can write something like:

```
    private void SetupEvents()
    {
        var observableA = Observable.FromEventPattern((e) => btA.Click += e, (e) => btA.Click -= e);
        var observableB = Observable.FromEventPattern((e) => btB.Click += e, (e) => btB.Click -= e);

        EventPattern<object> lastA = null;
        EventPattern<object> lastB = null;
        var observableG = observableA.CombineLatest(observableB, (rA, rB) =>
        {
            if (lastA == rA || lastB == rB)
                return null;

            lastA = rA;
            lastB = rB;
            return new Tuple<EventPattern<object>, EventPattern<object>>(rA, rB);
        }).Where(p => p != null);

        observableG.Subscribe(r => Trace.WriteLine("A + B"));

        // or use ToEvent to generate another standard .NET event
        //observableG.ToEvent().OnNext += GEvent;
    }

    //void GEvent(System.Reactive.EventPattern<object> obj)
    //{
    //    Trace.WriteLine("A + B");
    //}
```

Basically I check if the latest results are different from the current result.
Maybe there is some native RX extension for your case but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 3):

I think that [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) is probably closest to what you are looking for. It provides helpers to turn events into observables, and a linq-style syntax that you can use to compose those observables.

Answer (score 1):

You can write such a class yourself. Here's a (very) trivial implementation:

```
public class TwoEventGroup
{
   private bool _eventAFired;
   private bool _eventBFired;

   public void EventAHandler()
   {
      _eventAFired = true;
      TestAndFire();
   }

   public void EventBHandler()
   {
      _eventBFired = true;
      TestAndFire();
   }

   private void TestAndFire()
   {
      if (_eventAFired && _eventBFired)
      {
         _eventAFired = false;
         _eventBFired = false;
         if (GroupEvent != null)
           GroupEvent();
      }
   }

   public event Action GroupEvent;
}
```

This is just a conceptual implementation, you'd probably want to have the event delegate as a generic, extend it to n events instead of just two, (maybe) deal with time outs between event firing, thinking about how this class will be extended (if at all), etc.

@spender suggestion of Rx is worthwhile (+1) but the library is geared towards asynchronous events and has a somewhat steep learning curve. It might be overkill if you just want simple groupings of known events, or events of the same type and not something entirely generic.